Erratic behaviour connecting steppers and brushed motors to the same ground
I am controlling three stepper motors using an Arduino and TB6600 drivers with two separate power sources:

5V DC, 0.5A max: Supplies the logic part of the TB6600 and the Arduino.
24V DC, 4A max: Powers the stepper motors (each set to 0.5A current).

The grounds of these power sources are kept separate.
The drivers are mounted on pcb shields, and everything is connected by wires.
This is the stepper driver unit used (and it already has capacitors in the input side), this is the bi-polar stepper motor datasheet (the real stepper is a custom version of this but this should be the closest datasheet available)  and this is the BDC motor driver board
Problem 1: EMI Issues with Stepper Motors
Everything works smoothly if the +24V and motor ground wires are kept away from the wires going to the stepper coils. However, due to physical constraints, when these wires are placed close to the stepper coil wires, the system becomes erratic:

Steps are missed.
Motors unexpectedly change direction.


Additionally, I use the same power sources and Arduino to control three small brushed DC motors via DRV8871 drivers. These motors are:

Powered at 24V, with current limited to 0.1A each.
Rated at 370Ω winding resistance, running without PWM (on/off control only).

For the DRV8871, the motor and logic grounds are shared, so the 5V and 24V power sources' grounds are connected through the driver.
Problem 2: Combining Stepper and Brushed Motor Circuits
When I connect the stepper motors and brushed DC motors simultaneously:

The stepper motors lose steps and exhibit erratic behavior.


Troubleshooting Attempts
I tested the stepper motor setup without the brushed motors by replacing the motor load with a 330Ω resistor at the driver’s motor output. Surprisingly, the problem persists:

The system still behaves erratically, missing steps.

Hypothesis
I suspect that EMI from the +24V power supply is the root cause of these issues.
Questions

Could the +24V power supply be causing EMI interference?
What steps can I take to mitigate this problem?

UPDATE:
I've tried to connect only 1 stepper and nothing else, (no BDC motors)  and I've loaded the example from AccelStepper library and there is something not working: missing steps and a weird behaviour when it changes direction. Here a video of the stepper. is it possible that is a wrong wiring?
Attached a rough schematic. It's a schematic but the real wiring and component positioning is really similar to the drawing

What kind of stepper code are you using?  primitive fixed step rates or optimized for acceleration.

I used an old but bug-free GRBL PANEL for Win via USB then GRBL-code for Uno. Awesome but there are newer more network capable types out now. like grblHAL.

I see missing decoupling capacitors on your stepper drivers. What does your layout look like?

Good point Winny

@D.A.S. I used accelStepper library, that can handle acceleration.

@winny, I didn't add any capacitors on the steppers. I have 0.1uF ceramic caps available (104), should I add them between A+ and ground, A- and ground,B+ and ground and B- and ground?

No, input side of the driver. Please post your OCB layout.

It' s not a single PCB, but several single components connected by wires. This is the stepper driver unit used (and it already has capacitors in the input side) and this is the BDC motor driver board

If you cannot measure Mgnd noise or 24V noise with AC 50 ohm method or tip/ring dual probe Ch1-2 method then you cannot  understand the problem of your layout which needs either very low ESL planes  or Star twisted pairs from the low ESR source. Plus you will need CM chokes and ferrite beads if noisy.  The noise will be conducted and radiated with crosstalk like your messy schematic that has ground loops and crosstalk.

I don't mean to throw everything up in the air...but what motor are you using and what is the maximum step rate you are shooting for? You may not need those massive current regulators in the TB6600.  A simple L/R drive might work better! From the video, it looks like you may be hitting a resonant frequency causing step loss.

Also, I noticed that in your video, the center does not appear to be rotating.  How is the step motor coupled to the load?

@whitegreg56 , no the load is firmly coupled

Do you have a link to the step motor you are using? What is the diameter of the plate you are spinning? Is it aluminum or steel? It seems to start to shake before it loses steps. I would definitely take the plate off and substitute a piece of tape wrapped around the shaft and find out if it works with that.

I know you are thinking it is a grounding problem...but it may not be! When the motor is decelerating the load, it is acting as a generator and can affect the power.

Missing stepper movement is a combination of the insufficient current limit, excessive Voltage ripple, mechanical cable drag, and insufficient torque per step to accelerate the momentum to the next pole within the step-time. Ideally, you have not only XY control with the current limit but max. acceleration and max velocity constants in G-code calculations.  Bit-banging Arduino code is too primitive.

increase stepper current 50% to see if the problem goes away or until the motors get too warm (>45'C) to touch.
replace 47 uF unknown cap with 1 mF low ESR cap.
slow down the stepper acceleration rate on motion start-stop then you can step faster up to constant velocity. Inertia matters!
get latest G-code compiled for Arduino and run from Windows via USB. (GRBL Panel is old, amazing but is bug-free, GRBL-HAL is more advanced)


This is a classic EMC compatibility situation with unknown conductive and radiative crosstalk from motor noise into the logic.
In order to solve the puzzle you need to measure how the crosstalk can be measured to make better or worse.

All motor pairs need to be sourced from the lowest source impedance with large low ESR caps much lower than the motor DCR using twisted pairs or STP properly terminated at source.

Ripple measurements need to be included from  AC coupled 50 ohm terminated coax. scope measurements for pwr/return and short ground clip or none with tip & ring 10:1 calibrated probe for ringing and crosstalk noise.

Motor cables need a number of turns around large ferrite core loop to raise common mode impedance to reduce crosstalk to see if performance improves.
After you improve on ripple results to meet your expectations, you will discver the problem and know how to fix it.  In the meantime update your question with ongoing test results in a list and photos of layout and signals.


There is still a possible software glitch but I assume you are using proven software would have tested without motors using resistors to reduce EMC.
It is most important to show a schematic and photo of your layout, including part numbers or values of ESR + C for decoupling caps, along with your DC ripple results.
Below, I am estimating your motor inductance and supply capacitance. The location of the cap can make a resonant loop that demands shielded twisted pairs, as each motor winding has an LC resonant frequency, as well as the BEMF generation of commutation noise. When these coexist, you can get large conducted and radiated noises. The exact frequency is unknown.


Thanks for the detailed answer. I need guidance:


Should I add caps only to the BDC motors or also to the steppers? I currently use a 47uF electrolytic and 0.1uF ceramic cap between ground and +24V DC at the DRV8871 input. The BDC motors have 370Ω winding resistance and run at full speed without PWM, controlling on/off shutter mechanisms. Current is set to 100mA via the DRV8871 ILIM resistor. What other caps do you recommend?


I can’t easily do oscilloscope measurements. I’d prefer standard EMI improvements first and only measure if needed.



Regarding the software I tried them separately and they are working, but i didn't try both using 240ohm resistor instead of brushed motors

Verify the software with no inductive load.

Missing steps also occurs when load exceeds torque, current. How isolated are they physically for inertia.

I've verified replacing the brushed motors with resistors and I found that the issue is still present, and is related to the proximity between +24V and motor ground to wires going to stepper coils. Is it possible that the EMI are caused not (only) by BDC motors but also by the power source? I've updated the question with the new info for better usability.

Verify your stepper waveforms with a dual probe do not change with BLDC motor activity,  Change the acceleration rate or step interval to test the fastest speed on the motor.  Verify the 24 V ripple then replace 47 uF with at least a 1mF low ESR cap next to the driver and measure AC coupled ripple into 50 ohm terminated DSO.  If you limit acceleration and not velocity, your stepper servo will work faster with enough margin for cable drag.

I don't think that the issue is related to max current/torque since the torque the motor has to apply is really low, but I'll try to increase current from 0.5A to 1A. Regarding the 47 uF cap I'm a bit lost: this cap is on the BDC motor driver DRV 8871, as suggested in the datasheet, not on the stepper driver TB6600. Up to now I'm trying to solve the emi interferences between +24V power supply and the steppers. As suggested, while I'm trying to solve this I've replaced BDC motors with resistors.once this problem is set I'll connect them and evaluate additional actions if needed

I thought I was referring to stepper motor current. Are the step pulses missing or does the stepper motor slip ?

Step pulses missing and also issues with direction

OK now you analyzed the problem. The fix needs more details but it looks like a bug.

I don't think so, because the same code for the steppers is working perfectly keeping the +24V and motor ground completely separate from 5v power supply (tb6600 is opto isolated) and distant from the other wires. The issue comes when i connect the logic and motor grounds together and i pack all the wires together

so I am waiting for your AC coupled 50 ohm terminated ripple measurements.  Beef up your grounds with flat braid wire. Make sure they are star connected to your source to not share current and add large mu ferrite to absorb the frequency of ripple. Include your test results before after with DSO photos. review all my recommendations.  You can put 10uF caps across your BDC motors since unipolar on/off to reduce crosstalk and larger caps across drivers not shown on schematic.

In order to exclude software issues Iìve loaded a bouncing example from the library and made a video. I've updated info on the question

The wiring to the TB6600 modules looks a bit odd when compared with the data sheet.  Are you grounding the right inputs?
The 8871 drivers aren't shown as having any capacitors nearby, as shown in the TI data sheet.
You may have to think carefully about the grounding and the manufacturer's recommendations.  The worst possibility is where the two power supplies' grounds end up being linked through some piece of equipment, rather than solidly linked.  But check the design guidelines.

Why do you say tb6600 wiring is odd? I thought that connecting +5v all together and step - and dir- to an arduino output each or vice versa (all ground together and dir+ and dir- to arduino outputs) was the same. 8871 have caps as in the datasheet. I tried to connect +24 ground and +5v ground directly at the single entry point but i didn't saw any difference

@Luigi the page I linked to shows the - inputs grounded, and the + inputs connected to the Arduino. You're connecting the + inputs to 5V and the - inputs to the Arduino.

I got it, but switching between the 2 configurations is only switching the logic, I do not expect any issue with this, tb 16600 is opto isolated so i'm switching on an LED basically

Unless you start scoping the DC bus ripple , signals and setup info, I can't help you.  The video looks like it is microstepping then erratic on one phase or direction.  Do you know how to measure differential with two probes?
